# MuleSoft : what is the root cause | Error sending HTTP request. (org.mule.api.MessagingException)

Tags: mule, httpconnection

I am getting this exception intermittently while making HTTP request to third-party APIs :

**Exception trace stack is**:

```
Error sending HTTP request. (org.mule.api.MessagingException)   


java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:719) 

java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValueIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:747) 


java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)     java.util.LinkedHashSet.(LinkedHashSet.java:169) 
com.ning.http.client.FluentCaseInsensitiveStringsMap.keySet(FluentCaseInsensitiveStringsMap.java:341) 

org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.createMuleResponse(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:347) 

org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.send(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:267) 

com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.grizzly.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.send(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:104) (194 more...)

    (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

We are not able to find the root cause of this issue as no code change is done. Could you please help us to resolve it